# Laravel Blog - canonical route does not work

Tags: php, laravel, routes, blogs

I built a small blog controller to add a blog to my website like http://example.com/blog/post

It works fine with the post id like: http://example.com/blog/1
But it doesn't work with http://example.com/blog/postTitle

Here is my code:

Routes:

```
Route::get('/blog/{blogPost}', ['as' => 'blogPost', 'uses' => 'BlogPostController@show']);
```

BlogPostControler.php :

```
public function show(BlogPost $blogPost)
    {
        return view('blog.show', [
                'post' => $blogPost,
        ]);
    }
```

views/blog/index.blade.php :

From here I link to the blog posts. When i change the `<a href="blog/{{ $post->title_slug }}">{{ __('blog.Read more') }}</a>` back to `<a href="blog/{{ $post->id }}">{{ __('blog.Read more') }}</a>` it works fine

```
<div class="box">
    @forelse($posts as $post)
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <h3>{{ ucfirst($post->title) }}</h3>
                    <p>{!! mb_substr(strip_tags($post->body), 0, 255) !!} ... <a href="blog/{{ $post->title_slug }}">{{ __('blog.Read more') }}</a> </p>

                </li>
            </ul>
        @empty
            <p class="text-warning">No blog Posts available</p>

    @endforelse

    </div>
```

As I said, it works fine with the id. What did I wrong? I can't figure it out.

Thank you all

I think I have to check whether the title_slug fits to the post id. But I don't know where.
I use Laravel v5.8.3

Comment: When you type hint the model in the function, it's expecting the ID. If you want to use the slug, then you'll have to query the model yourself instead of type hinting

Comment: Or you can use [explicit model binding](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/routing#explicit-binding)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may change the route key/database column that is used when binding a model.

As per [the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/routing#implicit-binding) (see: *Customizing the key name*):

> If you would like model binding to always use a database column other than id when retrieving a given model class, you may override the getRouteKeyName method on the Eloquent model.

```php
public function getRouteKeyName(): string
{
    return 'title_slug';
}
```

After you add that function to your `BlogPost` model, using the slug in the URL should work.

Comment: he's in version **5.8.3**

Comment: Yes, I changed the documentation link just now. Laravel 5.8 also supports this.

Comment: @RaphaelW if it's a new project, use laravel 10. there is no point in using v5 for new projects. It's support has ended long ago.

Comment: @itachi unfortunately it's an old project. I'll upgrade it this year. But it's a multilanguage custom project with over 20 sites and domains. This will take a while ;)